# ArrayList not outputing correctly

Tags: java

So, My class called `InventoryList` that has an Arraylist, and has methods that add new books, deletes a book, get the price of all books, ect.

Now, it all works but when I run it and I try to output the list of books i added it all come out the same. So if I input the following:

> - ISBN: 1111 ----- ISBN: 2222
> - Ttile: cool ------- Ttile: why
> - Year: 2018 ----- Year: 2018
> - Author: llama -- Author: llama
> - Price: 20.00 ---- Price: 20.00

When I out put it as a list I get

> 2222 why 2018 llama 20.00
>
> 2222 why 2018 llama 20.00

I don't know whats wrong, and I've searched everywhere.

What is wrong with my code?

This is the `Inventory class` where I store the ISBN, title, year, author, and price.

```
package bookStore;

public class Inventory {

private int isbn;
private String title;
private int year;
private String author;
private double price;

public Inventory() {
    this.isbn = 0;
    this.title = "";
    this.year = 0;
    this.author = "";
    this.price = 0.0;
}

public Inventory(int isbn, String title, int year, String author, double price) {
    this.isbn = isbn;
    this.title = title;
    this.year = year;
    this.author = author;
    this.price = price;
}

//Getters
public int getIsbn() {
    return this.isbn;
}
public String getTitle() {
    return this.title;
}
public int getYear() {
    return this.year;
}
public double getPrice() {
    return this.price;
}
public String getAuthor() {
    return this.author;
}

//Setters
public void setIsbn(int isbn) {
    this.isbn = isbn;
}
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
public void setYear(int year) {
    this.year = year;
}
public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
}
public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
}

public String toString() {
    return ("ISBN: " + isbn + "\t" 
            + "Title: " + title + "\t"
            + "Year: " + year + "\t"
            + "Author: " + author + "\t"
            + "Price: " + price);
 }
}
```

This is the **Edited** `InventoryList` class with the ArrayList and it's methods.

```
package bookStore;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class InventoryList {

private int isbn;
private String title;
private int year;
private String author;
private double price;
Inventory books = new Inventory(isbn, title, year, author, price);
ArrayList<Inventory>list = new ArrayList<Inventory>();



//adding new books
public void addBook(int isbn, String title, int year, String author, double price) {
        list.add(new Inventory(isbn, title, year, author, price));
}

//delete a book using its ISBN number
//given by professor
public void delete(int isbn) {
    int index = 0;
    for(Inventory listBook : list) {
        if(books.getIsbn() == isbn) {
            index = list.indexOf(listBook);
            delete(index);
        } 
    }
}

//Searches for a book
public int searchBook(int isbn) {
    int index = 0;
    for(Inventory listBook : list) {
        if(books.getIsbn() == isbn) {
            index = list.indexOf(listBook);
        }
    }
    return index;
}

//print out books of year chosen by user
public void bookYear(int year) {
    for(Inventory listBook : list) {
        if(books.getYear() == year) {
            list.indexOf(listBook);
        }
    }
}

//print out the sum of all books price
public double priceAll(double price) {
    int price1 = 0;
    for(Inventory listBook : list) {
        if(books.getPrice() == price) {
            list.indexOf(listBook);
            price1 += price;
        }
    }
    return price1;
}

//print out all books
public void listBooks(int isbn, String title, int year, String author, double price) {
    
    for(Inventory listBook : list) {

        System.out.println(listBook.getIsbn() + "\t"
                + listBook.getTitle() + "\t"
                + listBook.getYear() + "\t"
                + listBook.getAuthor() + "\t"
                + listBook.getPrice());
        
    }
}
}
```

**Edit**:This is the Main I'm using

```
package bookStore;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class InventoryClient {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int isbn = 0;
    String title = "";
    int year = 0;
    String author = "";
    double price = 0.0;
    int menu = 0;
    int isbn2 = 0;
    int isbn3 = 0;
    
    InventoryList book = new InventoryList();
    
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    do {
        System.out.println("\n1 - New Book");
        System.out.println("2 - Books By Year");
        System.out.println("3 - Total of Inventory Price");
        System.out.println("4 - Search Book");
        System.out.println("5 - Erase Book");
        System.out.println("6 - List of All Books");
        System.out.println("7 - Exit");
        System.out.print("\nEnter Number from Menu: ");
        menu = scan.nextInt();
        
        if(menu == 1) {
            book.addBook(isbn, title, year, author, price);
            System.out.print("Enter ISBN: ");
            isbn = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter Title: ");
            title = scan.next();
            System.out.print("Enter Year: ");
            year = scan.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter Author: ");
            author = scan.next();
            System.out.print("Enter Price: ");
            price = scan.nextDouble();
        }
        if(menu == 2) {
            
        }
        if(menu == 3) {
            
            System.out.println(book.priceAll(price));
            
        }
        if(menu == 4) {
            System.out.println("Enter ISBN of Book you wish to find: ");
            isbn3 = scan.nextInt();
            book.searchBook(isbn3);
        }
        if(menu == 5) {
            System.out.println("Enter ISBN of Book you wish to delete: ");
            isbn2 = scan.nextInt();
            book.delete(isbn2);
            System.out.println("Book Deleted"); 
        }
        if(menu == 6) {
            book.listBooks(isbn, title, year, author, price);
        }
    }while(menu != 7);//Exit
        System.out.println("\nGood Bye!");
 }
}
```

Comment: Your `listBooks()` method does not make any sense. It simply does not use your list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
public void addBook(int isbn, String title, int year, String author, double price) {
    list.add(books);

    books.setIsbn(isbn);
    books.setTitle(title);
    books.setYear(year);
    books.setAuthor(author);
    books.setPrice(price);  
}
```

Should be:

```
public void addBook(int isbn, String title, int year, String author, double price) {
    books.setIsbn(isbn);
    books.setTitle(title);
    books.setYear(year);
    books.setAuthor(author);
    books.setPrice(price);

    list.add(books);
}
```

And, this:

```
public void listBooks(int isbn, String title, int year, String author, double price) {
    for(Inventory listBook : list) {

        books.setIsbn(isbn);
        books.setTitle(title);
        books.setYear(year);
        books.setAuthor(author);
        books.setPrice(price);

        System.out.println(books.getIsbn() + "\t"
                + books.getTitle() + "\t"
                + books.getYear() + "\t"
                + books.getAuthor() + "\t"
                + books.getPrice());
        //return listBook;
    }
//return books.getIsbn();
}
```

Should be:

```
public void listBooks() {
    for(Inventory listBook : list) {

    System.out.println(listBook.getIsbn() + "\t"
                + listBook.getTitle() + "\t"
                + listBook.getYear() + "\t"
                + listBook.getAuthor() + "\t"
                + listBook.getPrice());
    }
}
```

**EDIT** This is wrong inside your main.

```
if(menu == 1) {
    book.addBook(isbn, title, year, author, price);
    System.out.print("Enter ISBN: ");
    isbn = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter Title: ");
    title = scan.next();
    System.out.print("Enter Year: ");
    year = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter Author: ");
    author = scan.next();
    System.out.print("Enter Price: ");
    price = scan.nextDouble();
}
```

You are first adding book with empty values, and then assigning values to variables.
You should put it like this:

```
if(menu == 1) {
    System.out.print("Enter ISBN: ");
    isbn = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter Title: ");
    title = scan.next();
    System.out.print("Enter Year: ");
    year = scan.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Enter Author: ");
    author = scan.next();
    System.out.print("Enter Price: ");
    price = scan.nextDouble();

    // this should be at end, after you assign values to variables
    book.addBook(isbn, title, year, author, price);
}
```

Comment: I can't believe it was the Main that was wrong! thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Don't try and lazily add your books. This

```
Inventory books = new Inventory(isbn, title, year, author, price);
ArrayList<Inventory>list = new ArrayList<Inventory>();

//adding new books
public void addBook(int isbn, String title, int year, String author, double price) {
        list.add(books);

        books.setIsbn(isbn);
        books.setTitle(title);
        books.setYear(year);
        books.setAuthor(author);
        books.setPrice(price);  
}
```

should look like

```
List<Inventory> list = new ArrayList<>();

// adding new books
public void addBook(int isbn, String title, int year, String author, double price) {
    list.add(new Inventory(isbn, title, year, author, price));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has couple of bugs let's fix one by one

1) To add Book object to list

```
//adding new books
public void addBook(int isbn, String title, int year, String author, double price) {
    list.add(new Inventory(int isbn, String title, int year, String author, double price));

}
```

OR

```
 //adding new books
public void addBook(int isbn, String title, int year, String author, double price) {
   Inventory books = new Inventory();
   books.setIsbn(isbn);
    books.setTitle(title);
    books.setYear(year);
    books.setAuthor(author);
    books.setPrice(price); 
    list.add(books);

}
```

2) To display all the books in list, just print the book properties

```
//print out all books
 public void listBooks(int isbn, String title, int year, String author, double price) {

for(Inventory listBook : list) {

    System.out.println(listBook.getIsbn() + "\t"
                + listBook.getTitle() + "\t"
                + listBook.getYear() + "\t"
                + listBook.getAuthor() + "\t"
                + listBook.getPrice());
}
```

Comment: I did that but now I get this when I run it'0 " " 0 " " 0.0'
'1111 aaaa 2018 sarid 20.0'

Comment: can you update complete code with main method and what you are adding @SaridRuiz

Comment: @SaridRuiz Your if(menu == 1) block is not good. check my answer